# Delete key does not work in lxqt

Tags: debian, lxqt

I am using Debian 10.1 with the lxqt desktop.

When I press the delete key, nothing happens. I can't delete any file.

Something curious that I have noticed is that when I use the live disc, in the default language (English) this key works well. However, if I use the "localization Support" option and select the Spanish language, the delete key stops working.

Does anyone know what happens and how can I activate this key again?

Comment: what does the key do when used in a text editor or in a terminal window?

Comment: happens when i use pcmanfm-qt

Comment: What's the associated hotkey in the menu *-> Edit -> Delete*?

Comment: It has no key defined